# Manipulating Nybbles and smaller in c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have an application that requires manipulating [nybbles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) and possibly even individual bits at a time. Is there a library in C# that can help me?

Comment: nybble is a perfectly valid spelling, but i will remove the extraneous tags.

Comment: Learn something new every day. However, nybble is as unattractive as Colour is ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`BitVector32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) to manipulate bits in a 32 bit integer and [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) to have an array of bits representing a set of boolean variables.

Also, it's pretty easy to write a couple functions to manipulate individual bits:

```
public bool GetBitValue(int integer, int bit) {
    return (integer & (1 << bit)) != 0; 
}

public bool SetBitValue(ref int integer, int bit, bool value) {
    if (value)
        integer |= 1 << bit;
    else
        integer &= ~(1 << bit);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A library is really unnecessary

```
uint myVar = 257;
const uint SOME_FLAG_A = 256 // 100000000
const uint SOME_FLAG_B = 16  // 000010000
const uint SOME_FLAG_C = 1   // 000000001

if(myVar & SOME_FLAG_A == SOME_FLAG_A)
   Console.WriteLine("Bit A is set!");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Bit A is not set.");

if(myVar & SOME_FLAG_B == SOME_FLAG_B)
   Console.WriteLine("Bit B is set!");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Bit B is not set.");

myVar = myVar | SOME_FLAG_B;

if(myVar & SOME_FLAG_B == SOME_FLAG_B)
   Console.WriteLine("Bit B is set!");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Bit B is not set.");

if(myVar & SOME_FLAG_C == SOME_FLAG_C)
   Console.WriteLine("Bit C is set!");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Bit C is not set.");
```